# Nested maven legacy project

Tags: java, maven

I am working in a java project, that builds using maven, and its structure its as follows:

```
root
├── A1
│   ├── B1
│   │   ├── C1
│   │   │   ├── D1
│   │   │   └── D2
│   │   └── C2
│   │       ├── D3
│   │       └── D4
│   └── B2
│       ├── C3
│       │   ├── D5
│       │   └── D6
│       └── C4
│           ├── D7
│           └── D8
└── A2
    ├── B3
    │   ├── C5
    │   │   ├── D10
    │   │   └── D9
    │   └── C6
    │       ├── D11
    │       └── D12
    └── B4
        ├── C7
        │   ├── D13
        │   └── D14
        └── C8
            ├── D15
            └── D16
```

every node in the above tree represents a pom file, root is the parent of A1 and A2, and A1 is the parent of B1 and B2, and it goes like that...

in this example there are only 2 child’s  per node, but that is a simplification for the purpose of this question.

This project is executed using the command `mvn clean tomcat7:run-war` in D13, D14, D15 and D16. Those 4 processes and a relational database interact with each other at runtime.

As you can imagine, there are dependencies withing all these modules. as an example

-D13 has C4 as a dependency.

-C4 has B1 as a dependency.

-And a lot more...

So now, lets say that I want to change a functionality that belongs to the process run by D13, the code I want to change its located in D1, so I have two options:

1. I run mvn clean install in root, that even with -DskipAllTest and ignoring checkstyle and PMD takes one hour
2. I find out exactly how dependencies between D13 and D1 are resolved, and I re build just D1, C1, B1, C4 and D13, in that exact order.

I am interested in the 2nd approach, and my question is: can Maven some how help me to know exactly what I ned to re build without me checking every pom ? the total pom count in this project is +320, and its quite an annoying task.

I am using Maven 3.5.4.

thanks in advance,

Facundo

Edit:
When I run clean install from root using the -T flag it fails, I dont know why, but that is not the prpblem that I want to solve here.

Comment: First use a more recent version of Maven. Second why do you need `mvn clean install´? Isn't `mvn verify` sufficient? If you like to build only parts it's useful to use `mvn -pl ... ` from root and select the parts you would like to build maybe with supplemental information like `--also-make` and/or `--also-make-dependents`...depending on your needs. How many LOC's do you have ? How long take the tests? Do you use parallel build?

Comment: Hi  khmarbaise, thanks for your comment. In the example above, I am changing D1, thats why I run ´mvn clean install´, so it intstalls the new version in my local repo. ´verify´ would try to run only the integration tests, wouldnt it? if I run ´clean install -T C1´ from root it fails. it does not support paralell build. regarding ´-pl´ and ´also make´ how would that work ? in my example, how can I tell D13 that there is a new D1 version using that tag ?

Comment: If `clean install -T C1´ from root it fails` this is the case you have a problem somewhere in your dependencies... `it does not support paralell build` where do you get this from? `´verify´ would try to run only the integration`  this not quite true because it runs the lifecycle and if you have integration test (failsafe plugin) they will run.. But if you use `install` it will run them as well because `verify` is part of the lifecycle...  See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference ...I have run builds with 800+ modules (-T..) ..

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, Thanks for your comment, again. Yes, probably dependencies are set in a sub optimal way, therefore I can not run -T. As I said, it is a legacy system that I am trying to work with.  I am very happy for you that you managed to make a +800 modules project run using -T flag, but mine does not work, and that is not my question. The ´verify´ approach seems interesting tho. How do you suggest me to use ´verify´ to find out what modules and in what order I need to build to avoind building everything from root? Thanks. Facundo

Comment: `Yes, probably dependencies are set in a sub optimal way, therefore I can not run -T. ` That means it is not set sub optimal way that means you have a bug in your build !!! To find out what is needed  to built you should check `mvn -pl ... ` in combination with `--also-make` and maybe `--also-make-dependents`...

Comment: makes sense, I am trying  ´ mvn clean install -pl D13 --also-make´ , not much luck yet, I will keep trying